# Background tasks in Ktor like "Hosted Service" in ASP.Net Core

Tags: kotlin, background-task, ktor

I'd like to know how to create a background tasks in Ktor like "Hosted Service" in ASP.Net Core.
I need to have a background task running indefinitly on my Ktor server.

I'm coming from a C# background and we handle this with "Hosted services" in c# asp.net core

Any suggestions, samples

Than you very much.
best regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality for background tasks in Ktor but you can use [background jobs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) from the `kotlinx.coroutines` library.